# Why is %cd% in the post-build commandline just giving me the letter Í?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I'm using .NET Core 1.1 in Visual Studio 2017 RC, and in the post-build command line, I want to pass the current directory to a script. However, when testing things out before writing the script I discovered that for some reason %cd% (which is supposed to give the current directory) just gives me the letter "Í". I have absolutely no idea why this is happening.

EDIT: Language is C#, OS is Windows 10 Professional 64-bit. My locale was English (United States), which was wrong. After updating it to English (Canada), the bug persists but this time is giving me an Ö . The problematic line is in the Post-build event command line box under Project Properties -> Build Events. I assume it executes in the same directory as the executable, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Does changing it to `"%cd%"` help?

Comment: It just prints the same character, but in quotes this time.

Comment: Then you'll need to add more details ([edit] them into your question). What language (locale) is your OS using? What is the actual current directory where you're testing this?

Comment: Updated. See the post for the info you asked for.

Comment: I use build events a lot, I can't think of why I would have need to use %cd%.  None of the event macros are of use ?  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c02as0cs.aspx